# Laravel ORM add not defined columns

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a new record in one of my tables in laravel doing this:

```
$reservation = Reservation::create([
        'user_id'   => $request->input('user'),
        'ticket_id' => $request->input('ticket'),
        'amount'    => $request->input('amount'),
        'date'      => Carbon::now() ]);
```

although I have been creating records like this successfully, for some reason whenever I try to create this, the following QueryException error is thrown:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into`reservations`(`date`,`updated_at`,`created_at`)`

I don't have any **updated_at** nor **created_at** columns on my table reservations table, neither on my model.

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `updated_at` and `created_at` override this property in your model Reservation.php

```
public $timestamps=false;
```

Here is from the doc:

> By default, Eloquent will maintain the created_at and updated_at
>   columns on your database table automatically. Simply add these
>   timestamp columns to your table and Eloquent will take care of the
>   rest.

Property coming from methods `setCreatedAt($value)` and `setUpdatedAt($value)` in Vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\Datebase\Eloquent\Model.php.

Comment: Wow! That was quick and right. Thank you. Still, can you give a brief explanation of why did that happen?

Comment: If this was helpful to you, mark his reply as the answer.